# Alter the conditions in a DatabaseCondition object

Tags: views, database

Would there happen to be a way to alter the conditions in a DatabaseCondition object? Say I have this:

```
DatabaseCondition Object
(
    [conditions:protected] => Array
        (
            [#conjunction] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [field] => search_index.type
                    [value] => node
                    [operator] => =
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [field] => DatabaseCondition Object
                        (
                            [conditions:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [#conjunction] => OR
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [field] => search_index.word
                                            [value] => foo
                                            [operator] => =
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [field] => search_index.word
                                            [value] => bar
                                            [operator] => =
                                        )

                                )

                            [arguments:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [changed:protected] => 1
                            [queryPlaceholderIdentifier:protected] => 
                        )

                    [value] => 
                    [operator] => IS NULL
                )

        )

    [arguments:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [changed:protected] => 1
    [queryPlaceholderIdentifier:protected] => 
)
```

I would like to make changes on the `conditions`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can grab the conditions array for the full query like this:

```
$conditions =& $query->conditions();
```

As you're getting the array by reference any changes you make to it (and the conditions within) will be reflected back on the query object before it's executed.

If you want to replace all of the conditions in the query you can simply overwrite that array with a new one (filled with conditions obviously).

It might be safer, though, to loop through the conditions array and remove/alter only the conditions that you need to change. This will make sure that conditions added by other modules will still get their chance to be included in the query.

Editing an existing condition is tricky (I haven't managed to get it to work yet though I haven't tried very hard!). I think your best bet is to rebuild the conditions you need to change from scratch and replace them rather than try to edit them directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`DatabaseCondition::condition($field, $value, $operator)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/function/DatabaseCondition%3a%3acondition/7), which adds another item below your `bar` value. But I think that it won't work for you, beacuse there could be another problem with the `$field` value.

This is the same problem preventing you from adding a new `DatabaseCondition` object to `$view->query->where` too.

I figured out that the `$field` value is a refference to an **actual field within fields section** of the `$view` object. Have e.g. a **taxonomy tags field** and a **view filter** that shows nodes only **with both terms** `foo` AND `bar`.

**This will result in:**

- adding two *(hidden)* fields into your query - called sth. like: `field_term_tags_1` and `field_term_tags_2` *(simplified)*
- adding a `DatabaseCondition` object with two conditions like: `field_term_tags_1|foo|=` and `field_term_tags_2|bar|=`

**So the final SQL will look sth. like:**

```
SELECT ..., field_term_tags_1, field_term_tags_2 
FROM ... 
WHERE field_term_tags_1 = 'foo' AND field_term_tags_2 = 'bar' ...
```

So in this case I'd recommend you to use your own PHP filtering in [`hook_views_pre_render()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) *(after the query has been made)* rather than messing with the `$view` object.